# How to make a LAN web server?

Tags: webserver, lan

i want to make a web server that can be accessed on a LAN but i am new and don't have much idea on networking and Ubuntu however trying my best to learn.
it just need to be able to serve website on a server to LAN clients.
help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Next time, try googling :) (I just typed Webserver ubuntu installation)

-- Edit: (thanks Wilf)

the recomended info source is help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Comment: You won't need `mysql` & `php` for a basic webserver... - some configuration will probably also be needed for components as well - the recomended info source is https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html .